# Instruction fetch stage

Tags: assembly, operating-system, computer-science, cpu-architecture

In Hamacher(famous Computer organization book) an instruction processing is being broken into 5 stages which run in one clock cycles each. The first stage is instruction fetch stage, which is given as:

```
Stage 1--Memory address<--[PC], Read memory, IR<--Memory data, PC<--[PC] + 4
Stage 2--Decode instruction, RA [R4], RB [R5]
Stage 3--RZ [RA] + [RB]
Stage 4--RY [RZ]
Stage 5--R3 [RY]
```

I can see that increment in PC can be done using Combinational ciucuits but after so much effort couldn't find how memory read, PC's assignment to memory address register and loading of instruction in IR can all be done in one clock cycle.

Comment: The memory read and possibly the increment need time, the rest don't. As long as those fit into 1 clock cycle, you are fine. Not sure what your problem is?

Comment: Thanks @Jester, after the fetch stage their are 2 stages which pertain to register transfer solely i.e. one stage for one register transfer. I couldn't understand, why didn't the author split instruction fetch(which certainly involves at-least 3 register transfer) into more stages?

Comment: In the example you provided, only stage 1 is fetch. Stage 2 is decode, which is another stage. And btw a lot of things is done by combinational circuits.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes the stage 2 is decode. You can see stage 3/4 and 5 are just register transfers mainly. They all are being kept in different stages, so why not divide stage 1 also in multiple stages?

Comment: Why? As Jester already said, all those can run concurrently and fit in 1 clock cycle (except waiting to get the data from memory). Even if not, why is this a problem? It's simply a convention for naming stages.

Comment: For example, [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/CompOrg/fetchDecode.html) there are 6 stages.

Comment: @m0skit0 I guess not because PC to memory address transfer must precede Read memory and both of these must precede IR<--Memory data. Except I don't have any problem with increment in PC because it is combinational circuit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83883/discussion-between-user1706482-and-m0skit0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, the purpose of pipelining is to reduce the amount of work that the CPU needs to do during a single cycle.  Pipelining will be most efficient when each stage takes roughly an equal amount of time, but inevitably some stage will have to take the longest amount of time and that is what will determine the maximum frequency of the processor.

So it's not really a question of whether all of the things in the instruction fetch stage can be done in 1 cycle, instead it's a question of whether doing this work takes a similar amount of time to the other cycles.

The 5-stage pipeline is a classic design, but it's not used is most CPUs designed today.  Most modern high performance CPUs have more pipeline stages.

I have copied the stages that you listed below with the what they are commonly named and I will reference them with a single letter.

```
Fetch     --Memory address<--[PC], Read memory, IR<--Memory data, PC<--[PC] + 4
Decode    --Decode instruction, RA [R4], RB [R5]
Execute   --RZ [RA] + [RB]
Memory    --RY [RZ]
Writeback --R3 [RY]
```

In the Fetch stage the CPU has to use the current PC to read from memory (typically reading the instruction cache).  In parallel it can have an ALU that calculates the next PC.  At the end of the cycle the data read from memory is latched in the IR and the next PC that has been calculated is latched in the PC.  So really this cycle only needs enough time to read from the instruction cache and store the result in a register.  The other steps are done in parallel and take less time.

The Decode stage takes the instruction and determines what type it is and sets a bunch of control logic for how the instruction will execute in the rest of the pipeline.  This includes determining which registers have the sources for the operation and reading the values from those registers.  There are also other things that it does for checking for conflicts between instructions.

The Execute stage actually performs the operation in most cases (for instance doing addition).

The Memory stage is separate from Execute because it might depend on Execute to calculate the address in memory that the load/store will access.

Finally the Writeback stage writes the final result to the register file.  It depends on having the result from the previous stages.

Overall each of these stages does a roughly equal amount of work, and it would be difficult to move part of the work from one stage to another.  Again in modern systems each of these stages is typically further subdivided into more stages.  But the 5-stage pipeline is a good starting point for understanding how pipelining works and each of the stages in it requires a similar amount of time and there is a logical dependency ordering between stages.

Comment: thanks @Gabriel , _(typically reading the instruction cache)_. solved it all!!